# Google Cloud Spanner - technical implication of 3 node recommendation in production

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, high-availability, google-cloud-spanner

I'm wondering if there is any technical implication behind that recommendation.

It can't be split-brain because even when configuring 1 node there are 3 instances in total running in different data-centers within the configured region, each having all the data.
So when configuring 3 nodes google will run 9 instances in total sharding the data as well.

I would be happy if anybody could provide information on what's behind that recommendation.

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"when configuring 1 node there are 3 instances"

Quickly correcting terminology to make sure we're on the same page, 1 node still has 3 **replicas**. Or, more fully: "When configuring your **instance** to have only 1 **node**, there are still 3 **replicas**". When you have 3 nodes, you still have 3 replicas, however each replica will have more physical machines assigned to it.

The reason 3 nodes is the recommended minimum for a 'production grade' instance is around the number of machines that are assigned. When working with highly available systems we need to consider the probability of a replica being unavailable (zone maintenance, unforeseen network issues, etc) combined with the probability of other simultaneous issues, such as physical machines failures.

It's true that even with 1 node Cloud Spanner can continue to operate if a replica becomes available. However, to provide the uptime guarantees of Cloud Spanner, 3 nodes reduces the probability of physical machine failures being catastrophic to the overall system.